# How to use mogrify command with graphicsmagick and node js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, mogrify

I checked the graphicsmagick documentation. However there is no information on using mogrify command with Graphicsmagick.

http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html

Currently the code mentioned below creates multiples copies of the file and doesn't rename them as per the original file.

```
gm('*.png').crop(985, 631, 461, 144).write('*.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Why not use ImageMagick or Imagick

Comment: @fmw42 Initially I had thought of using imagemagic with nodeJS but on the github page its mentioned that it has been unmaintained since long. https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick

Comment: Has there been any solution to accessing "mogrify" using the GM node package?